# Can button labels be shown as passwords with asterisk in android

Tags: android, button, passwords

I have a requirement where my login form has pasword entry in the form of buttons.
This is my layout xml.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background= "@android:color/black"
        tools:context=".LoginActivity" >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:text="Password"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="65sp"
            android:layout_height="65sp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#00ff10"
            android:textSize="45sp" 

            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="65sp"
            android:layout_height="65sp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button01"
            android:textColor="#00ff10"
             android:textSize="45sp"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_width="65sp"
            android:layout_height="65sp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button02"
            android:textColor="#00ff10"
             android:textSize="45sp"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="65sp"
            android:layout_height="65sp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
            android:textColor="#00ff10"
            android:textSize="45sp"       
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:text="Login" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:text="Reset" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is Activity code snippet

```
  switch (v.getId()) {
   case R.id.button1:
     b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    int i3 = Integer.parseInt(b3.getText().toString());
    if(i3<=8)
    i3 = i3+1;
    else
    i3 = 0; 
    b3.setText(String.valueOf(i3));

    break;
```

[image]

Clicking on the buttons as many times will show the click number like a counter. 
So if the password is 1234, click on the first button once, on second button twice
, on third button thrice and fourth button four times.
I have this implemented, but trying to figure out a way to hide the label using an asterisk *
after the user has clicked on the button and seen the entered value before the * shows up.
I would want to know if this can be done by this approach?

Comment: you can change text of button in OnClickListener of each button.

Comment: Hi yahska, can a delay be induced on click so that the user can see for some time the value that was chosen? Not sure how to change text using setText, it showed * at all times when i tried. I updated my question with Activity code snippet.

Comment: Now as per my understanding of the question, you can use text box instead. when user will input one digit in that use for TextWatcher and check for onTextChanged. and if  he has inserted one digit then disable that text so that it will be more convinient for you. and if user insertesd wrong digit then you r already having reset facility. so thr will be no issues for that.

Comment: and if you want to introduce some time in between that then use threads for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is on click of any of this buttons set the text of other buttons to *.

in `Activity` create 4 int variables and 4 button variables.

```
int pass1,pass2,pass3,pass4;
Button button1,button2,button3,button4;
```

initialize all the buttons in `onCreate`.

in onClick do:

```
if(v.getId()==R.id.button1){
    pass1=(pass1+1)%10;
    button1.setText(""+pass1);
}else{
    if(pass1!=0)
        button1.setText("*");
}

if(v.getId()==R.id.button2){
    pass2=(pass2+1)%10;
    button2.setText(""+pass2);
}else{
    if(pass2!=0)
    button2.setText("*");
}
```

same for all the buttons

Your password is:

```
String password=""+pass1+pass2+pass3+pass4;
```

Comment: Hi Vipul, This suggestion came close to my requirement thanks! Though i am still strying to sort of fade the label to * after an interval of 2 seconds. can that be feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this code for the EditText

```
editText.setHint("Password");
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: Hi John, i am not using ant editText in my code. Where are you suggesting i use this code you provided? Please refer the UI image I added.

Comment: Hi, I would try replacing the label with an edittext and hide the keyboard.